# Integrating an image gallery plugin with an image zoom in function plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this site works on a points system, so i'll like to stress i'm a developer just starting out and i'm new to this site. Please be nice!!!

I have a slight problem with developing what i'm trying to achieve, i believe this maybe, predominately a HTML issue. I have downloaded two plugin's one being an image zoom function and the other is an image gallery with thumbnails.

The challenge i'm facing is integrating the two functions together, as both functions require an  i can't find a "clean" way to merge these two pieces of script together. Is there anyone out there that knows how i can merge these two script together?

Image zoom HTML

```
        <a class="zoom" href="css/product-gallery/item1.jpg"><img class="product-gallery" src="css/product-gallery/item1.jpg" alt="img1"></a>
```

Image gallery with Thumbnails HTML

```
<a class="thumb" href="css/product-gallery/item1.jpg" title="Title #0"><img src="css/thumbnails/thumb2.jpg"/></a>
```

[Click here for Image zoom code](http://iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/productsFinal.html)

P.S "It's not a lightbox effect i'm after, it's more an eCom image zoom function i'm after"

Comment: I've just added the site links above

Comment: click here for image gallery code  http://iamnatesmithen.com/gallery/example-1.html

Comment: If i understand you correctly you have a bunch of thumbnails, that when clicked will display a larger version of the image? What you need is lightbox http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: @OldRed that's correct. Then when you hover over the the larger image you can zoom in on the image. It's not a lightbox effect i'm after, it's more an eCom image zoom function i'm after?

Answer (score 0):

Having them both (lightbox zoom + on hover zoom) doesn't really make much sense, you should choose one and go with it. Lightbox is very easy to use and will do exactly what you want so i'd go with that. Quick little example: -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#imageGallery a').lightBox();
});
</script>

<div id="imageGallery">
   <a href="image-you-want-to-zoom"><img src="thumbnail-image" /></a>
</div>
```

If a 'lightbox-like' function is not what you're after, then try something like this:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom

And for some quick mock-up code of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/cvjsN/

Comment: is this function similar to ...http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-Skinny-Jeans-In-Dark-Wash/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2174294&cid=4208&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Blue

Comment: from what's i've gather the code above just create a lightbox, however doesn't enable me to zoom in the image to few in further detail. I think you've misunderstood my question slightly...

Comment: Here's an example of what i'm after ...  http://www.oki-ni.com/mens-tops/apc-mens-pocket-detail-t-shirt/invt/apc1116ant

Comment: I've added this code to my image gallery i still can't get it to work! http://iamnatesmithen.com/gallery/example-1.html

Comment: Have you added/referenced the plugins?

Comment: A quick look at your source and you haven't included the 'ex' id that your jQuery code is referencing in the right place (it's on the thumbnail, you want it on the zoom image) so i'm not surprised it isn't working. Spend some time reading over the documentation on the website I linked above, it's simple enough to implement